# Does this identity for expectations hold?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, expected-value

Let us have a random set $S \subseteq [0,1]$ drawn from some distribution. Let $\delta(x) = \lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} P(S \cap [x,x+y] \neq \emptyset)/y$. Assume that the limit exists for all $x$. Does it hold that
$$
E[|S|] = \int_0^1 \delta(x)\, dx
$$

Comment: If $S$ is drawn uniformly from all subsets then you'd expect $P(S \cap [x,x + y] \neq \varnothing)$ to be $1$ for all $y > 0$, but it's $1/2$ when setting $y = 0$. The outcome of $\lim_{y \to 0^+}$ may then depend on your precise definition of limit, but it is reasonable to take it to be $1/2$, which makes $E(|S|) = 1/2$, as one would expect (since every element has a $50\%$ chance of being in $S$). But this is all hand-wavy; in actuality, I doubt that the question is well-defined measure-theoretically.

Comment: Thanks! you made me realize there was a mistake in the question; I have fixed it. In the case you describe, $E[|S|]$ is infinite. $|S|$ is the absolute value, not the measure.

Comment: I assume that with “well-defined”, you mean “the limit exists”?

Comment: Yes. I have changed it accordingly.

Comment: (I think I have a proof. I will post it here once I write it up. I just want to say this so that people don't waste time writing up the proof too)